# Just started TKinter and can't seem to fix this error tkinter.TclError

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I just stared learning TKinter by coding along with a youtuber. and just cant seem to find the error, i tried tracing back the whole code without success. The video is about a year old, and idk if some syntax changed or if i just don't see the mistake i made

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class MyGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root= tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x900')

        self.lable= tk.Label(self.root, text="Your message", font=('Ariel', 18))
        self.lable.pack(padx= 10, pady=10)
       
        self.textbox= tk.Text(self.root, font=('Arial', 15)) 
        self.textbox.pack(padx= 10, pady= 10)

        self.check_state = tk.IntVar()
        self.check= tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text= "Show Messagebox", font= ("Ariel", 18), variable= self.check_state)       
        self.check.pack(padx= 10, pady= 10)

        self.botton = tk.Button(self.root, text= 'Show Message', font= ('Arial', 18), command= self.show_message)
        self.botton.pack(padx= 10, pady= 10)  

        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_message(self):
        if self.check_state.get() == 0:
            print(self.textbox.get('1.0', tk.END))
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(text= "Message", message= self.textbox.get('1.0', tk.END))

MyGUI()
```

This just works fine,

`if self.check_state.get() == 0:`

But

`if self.check_state.get() == 1:`

will just throw me an:
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-text": must be -default, -detail, -icon, -message, -parent, -title, or -type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem, though not in an entirely intuitive way. It's telling you that `text` is not a valid option for the `showinfo` method.

Instead of `text`, I'm guessing you were intending to use `title`:

```py
messagebox.showinfo(title= "Message", message= self.textbox.get('1.0', tk.END))
#                   ^^^^^
```